# Calling a variable from a classmethod function to a normal method

Tags: python, class

I would like to call a variable from a classmethod to a different method inside the same class:

```
class A():
    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        cls.g = 5
    def c(self):
        if self.g < 1:
            print("TestA")
        else:
            print("TestB")
```

When doing:

```
x = A()
x.c()
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'g'
```

I've read and searched for a similar case but haven't found one. Most deal with calling variables from the init method and that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Not sure why I received -1 for this question...

Comment: That probably happened, because your question is very basic. And the error you received answers your problem already. If something does not have `something else` as an attribute, that `something else` wasn't added. It's then an issue of finding out why it wasn't added. Was it forgotten? Was it added in the wrong place? Does it depend on operation order, which was done wrong...?

Comment: Note: you call *functions*, not variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't run `.b()` beforehand, your `.g` doesn't exist,...at all.

Add an `__init__` function to your class and declare `.g` there to make sure it exists at least.

Comment: Or just add a `g = None` to your class…

Comment: `g = None` will just turn the `AttributeError` into a `TypeError` in Python 3, since you can't compare `None` to `1`.

Comment: Indeed, but it'll help identify and find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You did not define `g` as a class attribute of the class `A`. This could be done this way:

```
class A():
    g = 7
```

but then in your code you are treating `g` as instance (`self.g`) and class variable (`cls.g`) at the same time. While this works (`self.g` will refer to `cls.g`) it may be confusing.